# Qual é o mínimo de tempo entre requisições aos feeds do StackOverflow?

Tags: suporte

Eu uso um cliente RSS que me avisa sobre novidades no site do StackOverflow ([feednotifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/)). Atualmente, está configurado para um feed a cada 4 minutos.

Qual é o tempo mínimo que eu posso usar de forma a não sofrer nenhum tipo de bloqueio?

Se eu configurar duas URIs de feeds distintos, esse mínimo seria global, ou por URI?

E quando forem URIs de sites distintos dentro da rede do StackExchange, o limite é global ou por site?

Comment: @Gabe sabe responder?